# no adding any record to database when i use mysql commands in php

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo, mysqli

I run the following code to add a new user to a table of data base, but this code doesn't work correctly.

```
<?php include ("database/configdb.php");//configuration file of pdo to database connection
if(isset($_GET['uname'])&&isset($_GET['pass'])&&isset($_GET['email'])&&isset($_GET['fname'])&&isset($_GET['lname'])){

//check username
$sql="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE uname=:username";
$rslt=$connect->prepare($sql);
$rslt->execute(array(":username"=>$_GET['uname']));
$num=$rslt->fetchColumn();
if ($num==1) { echo "exist"; exit();}
else{
    //end check username
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (fname,lname,uname,password,email,avatar,bdate,rdate,degree,popularity,sex,lock,lang,country,phone) VALUES(:fname1,:lname1,:uname1,:pass1,:email1,'','','','','','','','','','')";
    $result=$connect->prepare($sql);
    $query=$result->execute(array(
        ":fname1"=>$_GET['fname'],
        ":lname1"=>$_GET['lname'],
        ":uname1"=>$_GET['uname'],
        ":pass1"=>$_GET['pass'],
        ":email1"=>$_GET['email']
        ));

    if ($query){
        echo "ok"; exit();
    }
    else{
        echo "error"; exit();
    }       
}   
}
 else
 {
    echo "invalid";
 }  
 ?>
```

when i run this code, the result that printed is "error".
how can resolve that? thanks...

Comment: What is your error when you run the query directly on the database?

Comment: You're assuming success without taking possible failure into account. This means, you're not checking for errors anywhere.

Comment: instead of a USELESS fixed "error" message, why not have the DB tell you what happened? http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a MySQL reserved word which is `lock`

Either wrap it in ticks, or rename it to something else.

```
INSERT INTO users ... sex,`lock`,...
```

Even though you have `''` assigned as the value to be used for it, the column name "lock" still needs to be wrapped in ticks.

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Checking for errors would have signaled the error, placed under your connection:

`setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)`

I.e.:

```
$connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

right after the connection is opened.

Consult: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php and get the real error.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.